# Python- checking value in array

Tags: python

How can I check if the value is in an array based on a user input. for example:

```
secret_word = ['h', 'a', 'n', 'g','m', 'a', 'n' ]

guess_word = input(str('enter your letter)
```

how can I use loop to check value of what user inputs exists in array? and if it doesn't exist how should I keep a record of these so letters are not allowed to be inputted by user. if possible can you write a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a blank list of guesswords and put it in whileloop , where guess_word not in secret_word it will append in that guess_words list, if found in secret_word it will exit and print the guess_words that was entered.

```
secret_word = ['h', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'm', 'a', 'n']
guess_word = raw_input(str('enter your letter'))
guess_words = []
while guess_word not in secret_word:
    guess_words.append(guess_word)
    guess_word = raw_input(str('enter your letter'))
print guess_words
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set like this:

```
unavailablechars = set()
c = input("enter your letter")
while c in unavailablechars:
     c = input("enter a different letter")
if c in secretWord:
.
.
.
else:
     unavailablechars.add(c)
```

A set is like an array with the exception that you can't have the same element twice or more times for that matter.

Edit to give a more precise answer. Since you want to make a hangman game, the easiest thing is to use a set with all of the characters and while that set is not empty read chars.

```
secret_word=set(['h', 'a', 'n', 'g','m', 'a', 'n' ])
unavail=set()
while len(secret_word)>0:
    c = input("enter your letter")
    while c in unavail:
        c = input("enter a different letter")
    unavail.add(c)
    secret_word.remove(c)
 print("You won")
```